# Matlab sytle variable editor in Wing IDE

Tags: python, matlab, wing-ide

I'm considering moving from Matlab to Python. I am trying Wing IDE. I found it very convenient but now I'm looking for some functionality like the command Windows and variable browser in Matlab. I know if I start a debug process, I can tweak variables in memory with Debug Probe, so Debug Probe acts pretty much like a Matlab command window. But it is inconvenient to start a debug process first every time. I would prefer to use the Python Shell tab for this. So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible that I can use the Python Shell tab just like the command Windows in Matlab?
2. Can I browse variables in the stack of a Python Shell in Wing IDE, preferablly with a GUI tool?

Answer (score 3):

I would definettly suggest using [Spyderlib](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/), it is basically a Matlab GUI representation of a python IDE. It provides a shell tab, variable browser, etc. Support for various systems and architectures, and open source.